How to add margin below the miniframe?
I want to add some margins below the miniframe, how can I do it?
As is:

To be:

\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[box]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[box]

\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\setbeamersize{mini frame size=0.5cm, mini frame offset=0.5cm}

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\end{document}


Please don't delete duplicates. They are useful sign-posts for future users with the same problem (in particular if the duplicate is as well written and clear as your question).

I undeleted it.

@ Sadegh Thanks!

You can redefine the miniframe headline like this:
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[box]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[box]

\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\setbeamersize{mini frame size=0.5cm, mini frame offset=0.5cm}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip20pt% <- change value here
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\end{document}



You are the best. Thanks <3

@Sadegh You're welcome!
